# Python BeautifulSoup webcrawling: Formatting output

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

The site I am trying to crawl is http://www.boxofficemojo.com/yearly/chart/?yr=2013&p=.htm. The specific page I'm focusing on now is http://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=catchingfire.htm.

From this page, I am having trouble with two things. The first thing is the "Foreign Gross" amount (under Total lifetime Grosses). I got the amount with this function:

```
def getForeign(item_url):
    response = requests.get(item_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
    print soup.find(text="Foreign:").find_parent("td").find_next_sibling("td").get_text(strip = True)
```

The problem is, I can print this amount out to the console, but I can't append these values to a list or write them to a csv file. For the previous data I needed to get on this site, I got the individual piece of information for each movie and appended them all to one list, which I then exported to the csv file.

**How can I get this "Foreign Gross" amount as a separate amount for each movie?** What do I need to change?

The second problem is related to getting a list of the actors/actresses for each movie. I have this function:

```
def getActors(item_url):
    source_code = requests.get(item_url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    tempActors = []
    print soup.find(text="Actors:").find_parent("tr").text[7:]
```

This prints out a list of actors: Jennifer LawrenceJosh HutchersonLiam HemsworthElizabeth BanksStanley TucciWoody HarrelsonPhilip Seymour HoffmanJeffrey WrightJena MaloneAmanda PlummerSam ClaflinDonald SutherlandLenny Kravitz
  - as so.

I am also having the same problem as I am having with the foreign gross amount. **I want to get each individual actor seperately, then append them all to a temporary list, and then later append that list to another full list of all the movies.** I did this with the list of directors, but since all the directors are links, but not all of the actors/actresses have html links, I can't do the same. Another issue right now is that there is no space between each of the actors.

Why are my current functions not working, and how can I fix them?

More Code::

```
def spider(max_pages):
page = 1
while page <= max_pages:
    url = 'http://www.boxofficemojo.com/yearly/chart/?page=' + str(page) + '&view=releasedate&view2=domestic&yr=2013&p=.htm'
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    for link in soup.select('td > b > font > a[href^=/movies/?]'):
        href = 'http://www.boxofficemojo.com' + link.get('href')
        details(href)

        listOfForeign.append(getForeign(href))

        listOfDirectors.append(getDirectors(href))
        str(listOfDirectors).replace('[','').replace(']','')

        getActors(href)

        title = link.string
        listOfTitles.append(title)
    page
```

---

listOfForeign = []

```
def getForeign(item_url):
    s = urlopen(item_url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
    return soup.find(text="Foreign:").find_parent("td").find_next_sibling("td").get_text(strip = True)

def spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'http://www.boxofficemojo.com/yearly/chart/?page=' + str(page) + '&view=releasedate&view2=domestic&yr=2013&p=.htm'
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        for link in soup.select('td > b > font > a[href^=/movies/?]'):
            href = 'http://www.boxofficemojo.com' + link.get('href')
            listOfForeign.append(getForeign(href))                
    page += 1


print listOfForeign
```

returns

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/younjin/PycharmProjects/untitled/movies.py", line 75, in 
    spider(1)
  File "C:/Users/younjin/PycharmProjects/untitled/movies.py", line 29, in spider
    listOfForeign.append(getForeign(href))
  File "C:/Users/younjin/PycharmProjects/untitled/movies.py", line 73, in getForeign
    return soup.find(text="Foreign:").find_parent("td").find_next_sibling("td").get_text(strip = True)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_parent'

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write a well-written question :)

Comment: I don’t understand why you can’t add the revenue to a list?

Comment: I am getting an error: listOfForeign.append(soup.find(text="Foreign:").find_parent("td").find_next_sibling("td").get_text(strip = True))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_parent'

Comment: Are you testing the code above that I posted? That code should work, but it's not what I want. Can you try replacing the print statement in the getForeign method with     return (soup.find(text="Foreign:").find_parent("td").find_next_sibling("td").get_text(strip = True)), and then calling the getForeign(href) method?

Comment: http://imgur.com/WRTGiQV

Comment: I believe https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.boxofficemojo.com%2Fmovies%2F%3Fid%3Dcatchingfire.htm&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 may be the cause.

Comment: I typed exactly what was in your image but I'm still getting an                                  return soup.find(text="Foreign:").find_parent("td").find_next_sibling("td").get_text(strip = True)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_parent' error

Comment: With BeautifulSoup4? Python2 or 3?

Comment: Python 2.7, Beautiful Soup 4

Comment: I am stumped. You have the exact same code as me, with different output?

Comment: I added the code I have right now at the bottom